# easy localizations is incompatible with intl

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Here is the error received:

> Because easy_localization >=3.0.0-nullsafety depends on
> flutter_localizations from sdk which depends on intl 0.18.1,
> easy_localization >=3.0.0-nullsafety requires intl 0.18.1. So, because
> emartconsumer depends on both intl ^0.17.0 and easy_localization
> ^3.0.1, version solving failed.

here are my dependencies:

```
  environment:
  sdk: ">=2.18.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  firebase_core_platform_interface: ^4.5.1
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.15
  firebase_core: ^1.24.0
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.9.0
  firebase_auth: ^3.11.2
  cloud_firestore: ^3.5.1
  image_picker: ^0.8.6
  firebase_storage: ^10.3.11z
  url_launcher: ^6.1.7
  progress_dialog_null_safe: ^1.0.7
  intl: ^0.17.0
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.3
  uuid: ^3.0.7
  flutter_local_notifications: ^12.0.4
  video_thumbnail: ^0.5.3
  path_provider: ^2.0.11
  photo_view: ^0.14.0
  video_player: ^2.4.10
  flutter_facebook_auth: ^5.0.6
  http: ^0.13.5
  smooth_page_indicator: ^1.0.0+2
  firebase_messaging: ^13.1.0
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.1
  pin_code_fields: ^7.4.0
  permission_handler: ^10.2.0
  easy_localization: ^3.0.1
  mime: ^1.0.3
  moor_flutter:
  path: ^1.8.2
  font_awesome_flutter: ^10.3.0
  flutter_polyline_points: ^1.0.0
  percent_indicator: ^4.2.2
  lottie: ^2.1.0
  flutter_native_image: ^0.0.6+1
  video_compress: ^3.1.2
  flutter_sound: ^9.2.13
  the_apple_sign_in:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.5
  dotted_border: ^2.0.0+3
  flutter_braintree: ^2.3.1
  flutter_rating_bar: ^4.0.1
  place_picker: ^0.10.0
  google_maps_flutter: ^2.2.2
  geolocator: ^9.0.2
  geocoding: ^2.0.5
  share: ^2.0.4
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.6.2
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  geoflutterfire: ^3.0.3
  razorpay_flutter:
  location: ^4.4.0
  flutter_stripe: ^7.0.0
  paytm_allinonesdk: ^1.2.0
  webview_flutter: ^4.0.1
  flutterwave_standard: any
  bluetooth_thermal_printer: ^0.0.6
  esc_pos_utils: ^1.1.0
  flutter_facebook_keyhash: ^0.0.4
  flutter_qr_bar_scanner: ^3.0.2
  syncfusion_flutter_datepicker: ^20.3.61
  mercadopago_sdk: ^1.3.0
  flutter_widget_from_html: ^0.9.0+1
  scroll_to_index: ^3.0.1
  rect_getter: ^1.1.0
  cloud_functions: ^3.3.9

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.11.0
```

How do i solve the flutter error. I am currently using the beta channel but i can switch back to stable anytime.

Comment: Upgrading to `intl: ^0.18.1` should work just fine. Have you tried that?

Comment: better to use intl: 0.17.0 in order for the other package to be compatible

Comment: Upgrading to intl: ^0.18.1 causes more compatibility errors, using intl: 0.17.0 does not solve the problem

Comment: Downgrading Flutter seems like the best way or probably migrating the entire project to v3